# Tag needed for "what's wrong with my plant, here are the symptoms" type questions

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a category of Q which asks for help identifying the cause of a problem, here's three examples:

[Some of my ferns have brown spots on the tips of their leaves. What causes that?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/53/some-of-my-houseplants-have-brownspots-on-the-tips-of-their-leaves-what-causes-t)

[Why did the stem suddenly weaken in my oriental poppy?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/363/sudden-stem-weakening-in-oriental-poppy)

[What is this white growth on my cactus?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-is-this-white-growth-on-my-cactus)

I think these are an important category for the site, because they're **real** questons, they're interesting, potentially difficult, and (I like to think) attractive and challenging for experts to answer.

So do does this category need a tag of its own?

The last example is tagged [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) which is OK but which is a valuable tag in its own right for tagging "What is this plant?" type questions. And that's a different type of question.

What about [failing-plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failing-plant)? or [symptoms](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symptoms)? or [troubles](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubles)? or [problem](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem)? or [problem-identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-identification) (bit long)?

[disease](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease) would be another possibility but sometimes if we have a failing plant we don't know if it's disease or pest or environment.

Comment: FYI, I created the [tag:diseases] tag for my [Lupin question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/168/26).  If you create a [tag:disease] tag, they should be synonyms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For questions like this, I think [diagnosis](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnosis) would be good. In essence, the user is requesting a diagnosis when posting a question like this.

Comment: ok i'll dip my toe in the water with a retag

Comment: and a tag wiki edit